# Assign different variable names (which are nil array) through a loop

Tags: ruby

I have a loop which should assign different variable names depending on filesname which are contained in an array.

Each variable is set as an empty array.

```
filenames = ['file1', 'file2']

filenames.each do |filename|
  "@data_" + "#{filename}" = []        # used @ as I need these variables externaly from the loop
end
```

This gives me the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
```

What I don't understand is if I use

```
filenames.each do |filename|
  p "@data_" + "#{filename}"
end
```

it renders correctly

```
@data_file1
@data_file2
```

And if I set an empty array through the loop

```
filenames.each do |filename|
  @data = []
end
p @data
#=> []
```

it works too...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 for trying to work it out yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a data structure rather than synthesizing instance variables<sup>1</sup> with meta-programming.

Why not just:

```
@data = filenames.inject({}) { |h, v| h[v] = []; h }
# => { "file1" => [], "file2" => [] }
```

Now you can just reference `@data['file1']` where you want the 'file1' Array object.

---

<sup>1. But for the record, here is one way:</sup>

```
class A
  def f x, y
    self.class.send :attr_accessor, x
    send "#{x}=", y
  end
end

a = A.new
a.f 'new_instance_variable', 12345
p a.new_instance_variable
```

Comment: Hash[pairs] is perhaps a somewhat cleaner way of creating a hash. Let's hope Ruby gets Enumerable#mash some day and we all agree how to create a hash from an enumerable.

Comment: `each_with_object` is simpler than `inject` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution, if you're sure about the sanitsed-ness of your filenames array, would be:

```
filenames = ['file1', 'file2']

filenames.each do |filename|
  eval "@data_#{filename} = []"
end
```

Comment: You should probably add that this [will not work anymore](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673#new) in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing in `"@data_" + "#{filename}" = []` is assigning empty Array instance (`[]`) to a String instance (`"@data_file1"`), hence `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end`

You should want to do is to assign `[]` to instance variable: `@data_file`, not string: `"@data_file"`.

You can achieve that with `instance_variable_set` method of class `Object`:

```
filenames = ['file1', 'file2']

filenames.each do |filename|
    instance_variable_set("@data_#{filename}".to_sym, [])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using string concatenation and interpolation in the same string...

something like

```
p "@data_#{filename}"
```

is the same as your

```
p "@data_" + "#{filename}"
```

Now this won't work because you are trying to say string = something else you need to evaluate the string

```
eval("@data_#{filename} = []")
```